Any shortcuts in solving a linear system
Given $X_i,Y_i,Z_i,W_i\in k$ (i=1,2,3), how to solve the following linear system?
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
\begin{vmatrix}
X_1 & X_2\\
W_1 &W_2 
\end{vmatrix} & \begin{vmatrix}
Y_1 & Y_2\\
W_1 &W_2 
\end{vmatrix} &\begin{vmatrix}
Z_1 & Z_2\\
W_1 &W_2 
\end{vmatrix}\\
\begin{vmatrix}
X_1 & X_3\\
W_1 &W_3 
\end{vmatrix} & \begin{vmatrix}
Y_1 & Y_3\\
W_1 &W_3 
\end{vmatrix} &\begin{vmatrix}
Z_1 & Z_3\\
W_1 &W_3 
\end{vmatrix}
\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 0 
\end{pmatrix}$$
One of the solutions is:
$$ \begin{pmatrix} x & y & z
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} \begin{vmatrix}
Y_1 & Y_2 & Y_3\\
Z_1 &Z_2 &Z_3\\
W_1 & W_2 &W_3
\end{vmatrix} &
\begin{vmatrix}
Z_1 & Z_2 & Z_3\\
X_1 &X_2 &X_3\\
W_1 & W_2 &W_3
\end{vmatrix}& \begin{vmatrix}
X_1 & X_2 & X_3\\
Y_1 &Y_2 &Y_3\\
W_1 & W_2 &W_3
\end{vmatrix}\end{pmatrix}  $$
But I do not know either how to verify it, or derive it cleverly.
Any hints or solutions are welcomed. Thanks!

Shouldn't that be $\pmatrix{0\cr 0\cr}$ on the right side?  The coefficient matrix has only two rows.  Of course the system is homogeneous, so a constant times a solution is a solution.

@RobertIsrael Thank you, sorry for the mistake. For the second, yes, I mean the above is a solution.

Here is one way to verify this. For example, we show that:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
X_1 & X_2\\
W_1 &W_2 
\end{vmatrix} \cdot  \begin{vmatrix}
Y_1 & Y_2 & Y_3\\
Z_1 &Z_2 &Z_3\\
W_1 & W_2 &W_3
\end{vmatrix}+ \begin{vmatrix}
Y_1 & Y_2\\
W_1 &W_2 
\end{vmatrix}\cdot \begin{vmatrix}
Z_1 & Z_2 & Z_3\\
X_1 &X_2 &X_3\\
W_1 & W_2 &W_3
\end{vmatrix}+ \begin{vmatrix}
Z_1 & Z_2\\
W_1 &W_2 
\end{vmatrix}\cdot \begin{vmatrix}
X_1 & X_2 & X_3\\
Y_1 &Y_2 &Y_3\\
W_1 & W_2 &W_3
\end{vmatrix}=0
$$
We expand those determinants of order $3$ in the last column to get:
$$ \begin{aligned}
LHS&= W_3\left( \begin{vmatrix}
X_1 & X_2\\
W_1 &W_2 
\end{vmatrix} \cdot  \begin{vmatrix}
Y_1 & Y_2\\
Z_1 &Z_2 \\
\end{vmatrix}+ \begin{vmatrix}
Y_1 & Y_2\\
W_1 &W_2 
\end{vmatrix}\cdot \begin{vmatrix}
Z_1 & Z_2 \\
X_1 &X_2 \\
\end{vmatrix}+ \begin{vmatrix}
Z_1 & Z_2\\
W_1 &W_2 
\end{vmatrix}\cdot \begin{vmatrix}
X_1 & X_2 \\
Y_1 &Y_2 
\end{vmatrix}\right)\\
&
\end{aligned}$$
which can be verified equaling to zero by applying the generalized Laplace expansion theorem (http://www.imvibl.org/imvibl/buletin/bultetin_15_2008/buletin_15_2008_5_7.pdf) $(n=4,r=2)$ to
$$ \det\begin{pmatrix}
X_1 &X_2 &X_1 &X_2\\
Y_1 &Y_2 &Y_1 &Y_2\\
Z_1 &Z_2 &Z_1 &Z_2\\
W_1 &W_2 &W_1 &W_2
\end{pmatrix}$$
Edit: The final argument is invalid if $\mathrm{char}(k)=2$ :(
